# How to display a list in datagrid

Tags: c#, list, datagrid

I'm trying to create a datagrid that will display data from a class object that I created. So far, with my current code, it will show the correct number of cells in the column I've coded, but it will not actually populate the data.

Object Class:

```
public class RCTask
{
    public long tID = 0;
    public string taskTitle;
    public TimeSpan startTime;
    public TimeSpan endTime;
    public TimeSpan hoursSpent;
    public bool sorted = false;

    public RCTask()
    {  }
```

The list is located on another form, so I am using a property to gain access to it.
DataGrid coding:

```
    private void bindTimes()
    {
        taskTimesSource.DataSource = Program.timesheetListI;
        gridTimes();
    }

    private void gridTimes()
    {
        timesGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

        DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn ID = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
        {
            CellTemplate = cell,
            Name = "idColumn",
            HeaderText = "ID",
            DataPropertyName = "taskTitle"
        };

        timesGrid.Columns.Add(ID);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to encapsulate the fields of `RCTask` class as properties.
For example, if you want to show the value of `taskTitle` in the `DataGridView`, you have to define the public property like this:

```
public class RCTask
{
    public long tID = 0;
    public string taskTitle;
    public TimeSpan startTime;
    public TimeSpan endTime;
    public TimeSpan hoursSpent;
    public bool sorted = false;

    public string TaskTitle
    {
        get
        {
            return taskTitle;
        }
    }

    public RCTask()
    { }
}
```

Secondly, you have to change the order of data setting process. 
Set `DataSource` after initializing table structure like this:

```
private void bindTimes()
{
    // Initialize table structure
    gridTimes();
    // Set data
    taskTimesSource.DataSource = Program.timesheetListI;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the data to populate. I added the variables as properties and it worked. Also, just to increase your learning in the new versions of C#, lambdas can be used for the get boilerplate. It can help condense the code. `public long TaskID => tID;
        public string TaskTitle => taskTitle;
        public TimeSpan StartTime => startTime;
        public TimeSpan EndTime => endTime;
        public TimeSpan HoursSpent => hoursSpent;`

Answer (score -1):

Try gridTimes method first,then set the datasourcefor grid

Comment: this should be a comment.